# Anytime I run npm install --force, I face this error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Am having this error when running npm i --force, npm i don't even run, it shows bunch of errors

```
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
```

npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/react-hook-form: aborted
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/heiscostly/.npm/_logs/2021-05-11T06_27_03_886Z-debug.log

Comment: is the error not self explanatory enough?

Comment: Try with sudo and check your proxy as mentioned in the error description

Comment: try to re-install npm to latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error itself explains that there is some issue with network connectivity.
Below mentioned questions will help you troubleshoot the issue

- Does this happen only for `react-hook-form` or it happens for all the packages?
- Does installation work without the `--force` parameter?
- Are you using the latest `npm` version? You can check using `npm -v`.
- Execute `curl https://registry.npmjs.org/react-hook-form` to check whether your computer can access the page. (If you can't or `curl` fails then there is a problem with your computer settings, not `npm`)

Comment: I've used a different internet connection and same error occurs

Comment: . Insatallation without --force doesn't work
. Yes am using the latest npm version

Comment: Does this happen only for `react-hook-form` or it happens for all the packages?

Comment: it happens in all packages

Comment: Try reinstalling `npm` or use some other computer. It is the only solution if feel would work out

Comment: STILL DIDN'T WORK OUT
DON'T GET ANOTHER COMPUTER TO RUN IT ON

Comment: Which OS Do you use?

Comment: Linux Ubuntu to be precise(Focal Fosa)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232218/discussion-between-atheesh-thirumalairajan-and-kedeh-costly).